# In what condition does error 23001 (restrict_violation) occur?

Tags: postgresql

From the name I was thinking an "ON DELETE RESTRICT" would trigger it, but that triggers an error 23503 (FK violation):

```sql
 create table a (id serial primary key);
 insert into a default values;
 create table b (id serial primary key, a_id integer references a (id) not null);
 insert into b (a_id) values (1);
 delete from a where id=1;


ERROR:  23503: update or delete on table "a" violates foreign key constraint "b_a_id_fkey" on table "b"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "b".
SCHEMA NAME:  public
TABLE NAME:  b
CONSTRAINT NAME:  b_a_id_fkey
LOCATION:  ri_ReportViolation, ri_triggers.c:2797
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having asked on IRC and checked the code, it looks a lot like 23001 does not currently occur anywhere in standard postgresql, though it could be generated by stored procs and the like.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/10137.1295623771%40sss.pgh.pa.us